# Why do my images look fine in Lightroom itself but poor quality when I export them?

Tags: lightroom, image-quality, export

I'm editing my night shots in `Lightroom` and use `Google Nik Collection` `Dfine2` to reduce the `noise`..
Noise reducing in `Dfine` is the last item in my workflow, and when I export image `.jpg` it has poor quality, I tried exporting without noise reduction (`Dfine2`) and quality is better.. 
So what is the problem? Can I somehow export with high quality `Noise Reduced` image?
[image][image]

Comment: That looks more like color banding due to lower bit-depth and jpeg compression than noise. Such banding often looks very similar to chrominance noise.

Comment: I gues I need to change export options

Comment: Yup, JPEG Quality was 60% in export options, set 100% and everything is fine, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks more like color banding due to lower bit-depth and jpeg compression than noise. Such banding often looks very similar to chrominance noise.

Increase the JPEG quality when you export so that it isn't as heavily compressed and the issue should be minimized.